# Fluent NHibernate - Unidirectional Mapping Between Parent and Children

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to pass a reference at load time of a parent to it's children without a relationship back to the parent from the child?

I would prefer to NOT have a mapped property for this purpose (i.e. prefer not to use bi-directional relationships for this purpose).

Comment: I guess it's not an option for you to add the new children from the parent every time you need to. I think your better option would be to take the approach @Fourth mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it with a linking table but you'd have to enforce one-to-many via code otherwise it could easily become a many-to-many. The jist of the linking table would be that it keeps the association between the parent and its children, rather than the child object itself.